# What is the magnitude of Complex random variable Gaussian Case?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent complex Gaussian random variables, $$X_1 \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma)$$
$$X_2 \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma)$$

If $X= aX_1 + bX_2$ where $a,b$ are constants then the complex Gaussian random variable $X$ is also Gaussian $$X\sim \mathcal{CN}(0,a^2\sigma+b^2\sigma)$$

My question is next, I have to find the distribution of magnitude and the square of magnitude of $X$ $$Y=|X| $$$$Z=|X|^2$$ Is the distribution Rayliegh and exponential ? If yes what are the mean and variance?

Cheers!

Comment: How do you know they should be Rayleigh and exponentially distributed respectively? I would be surprised if they were

Comment: for your first problem, $Y$, given the symmetry about $0$ it may be useful to think of the cumulative distribution